# Warning: Division by zero message

Tags: php

I'm trying to create a rating system on my site but when I entered the following code, it gives me the warning, "Warning: Division by zero in /home/*****/public_html/**** on line 38"

```
<?php 
 // Connects to your Database 
  include ('config.php');

   //We only run this code if the user has just clicked a voting link
 if ( $mode=="vote") 
 { 

 //If the user has already voted on the particular thing, we do not allow them to vote again    $cookie = "Mysite$id"; 
    if(isset($_COOKIE[$cookie])) 
        { 
        Echo "Sorry You have already ranked that site <p>"; 
        } 

 //Otherwise, we set a cooking telling us they have now voted 
    else 
        { 
        $month = 2592000 + time(); 
        setcookie(Mysite.$id, Voted, $month); 

         //Then we update the voting information by adding 1 to the total votes and adding their vote (1,2,3,etc) to the total rating 
 mysql_query ("UPDATE vote SET total = total+$voted, votes = votes+1 WHERE id = $id"); 
        Echo "Your vote has been cast <p>"; 
        } 
 } 

 //Puts SQL Data into an array
 $data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM vote") or die(mysql_error()); 

 //Now we loop through all the data 
 while($ratings = mysql_fetch_array( $data )) 
 { 

 //This outputs the sites name 
 Echo "Name: " .$ratings['name']."<br>"; 

 //This calculates the sites ranking and then outputs it - rounded to 1 decimal 
 $current = $ratings[total] / $ratings[votes]; 
 Echo "Current Rating: " . round($current, 1) . "<br>"; 

 //This creates 5 links to vote a 1, 2, 3, 4, or 5 rating for each particular item 
 Echo "Rank Me: "; 
 Echo "<a href=".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."?mode=vote&voted=1&id=".$ratings[id].">Vote 1</a> | "; 
 Echo "<a href=".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."?mode=vote&voted=2&id=".$ratings[id].">Vote 2</a> | "; 
 Echo "<a href=".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."?mode=vote&voted=3&id=".$ratings[id].">Vote 3</a> | "; 
 Echo "<a href=".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."?mode=vote&voted=4&id=".$ratings[id].">Vote 4</a> | "; 
 Echo "<a href=".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."?mode=vote&voted=5&id=".$ratings[id].">Vote 5</a><p>"; 
 } 
 ?>
```

P.S.
How do I change the check from using cookies, to a mysql database. I want it to check the database to see if the person has just rated.

Comment: You can't simply change cookies by mysql storage. You'd need some way to relate the users to their db records (e.g. a login system).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On line 38, you have `$ratings[total] / $ratings[votes]`.  The problem here is that if the amount of votes in the ratings array is 0, you're dividing by zero.

`$current = $ratings['votes'] > 0 ? $ratings['total'] / $ratings['votes'] : 0;`

Comment: If you like it, @user3078799, you should mark it as an answer.  There are some other issues in your code though, including potential SQL injection and other security issues.  I'd recommend reading [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) if you care about this and are looking towards any career in the field.

Answer (score 3):

Line 38:

`$current = $ratings[total] / $ratings[votes];`

should probably be

`$current = $ratings['total'] / $ratings['votes'];`

not to mention the other problems in your code.